# GridBagLayout cant get layout right

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm new to GridBagLayout but I tried to use the standard convention that I could
find which was to draw out my idea on a piece of grid paper and then try and translate the grid values into gridbag...

my goal is to make the layout like you see below:

[image: Desired layout]

it currently looks like this:

[image: Actual layout]

any idea's as to why?

the exact dimensions i'm looking for if you think of a grid with the upper left hand corner being 0,0
for

1. the red in panel in the goal picture: start at column 0, span 10 columns, with height 1 row
2. for the black panel: start at column 0, row 1, span 10 columns, with height 20 rows
3. for the blue panel: start at column 0, row 21, span 10 columns, with height 1
4. for the green column: start at column 10, row 0, span 16 columns, with height 7
5. for the purple column: start at column 10, row 7, span 16 columns, with height 16

here is my source code:

GBC is a helper class that extends GridBagConstraints, the constructor used is

GBC(int startingX,int startingY,int width,int height)

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Demo extends JApplet
{

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

    public void init()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initComponents()
    {
        //set the layout of the content pane to gridbag layout
        GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(gridBag);

        Rectangle rect = getContentPane().getBounds();

        panel1.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel4.setBackground(Color.orange);
        panel5.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        add(panel4, new GBC(10, 0, 16, 7).setFill(GBC.BOTH).setWeight(1.0, 1.0));
        add(panel1, new GBC(0, 0, 10, 1).setFill(GBC.BOTH).setWeight(1.0, 1.0));
        add(panel3, new GBC(0, 21, 10, 1).setFill(GBC.BOTH).setWeight(1.0, 1.0));
        add(panel2, new GBC(0, 1, 10, 20).setFill(GBC.BOTH).setWeight(1.0, 1.0));
        add(panel5, new GBC(10, 7, 16, 16).setFill(GBC.BOTH).setWeight(1.0, 1.0));
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated (but please explain your logic)

Comment: GridBagLayout does not make the columns equal size by default.  The columns are sized based on the contents of the Swing components that are placed on the main JPanel.  You should create the contents of each of the 5 JPanels first, then try and group them together on a main JPanel with the GridBagLayout.

Comment: well thats counter intuitive xD, you'd think you'd want to design the layout first. anyway thanks for that i'll give it a try.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc it still looks exactly the same after adding the components :( any idea why these row and column values aren't working?

Comment: Not without an SSCCE.  Preferably runnable.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: @nachos : About `Left` and `Right` side, do they need to be of different sizes ? If yes, a simple change in `weightx` values in the last three `addComp(...)` calls, for `leftPanel (smaller value)`, `greenPanel` and `magentaPanel` (same but higher values for both of these JPanels) will do.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Missing GBC class.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can easily accomplish this by using a `GridBagLayout`.

Considering `contentPane` with `GridBagLayout` as its layout, you can divide the `JPanel` into three parts now. A single left side `JPanel` (with GridBagLayout, and which will contain those `RED`, `BLACK` and `BLUE` `JPanel`s), and the right side consisting of two `JPanel`s, i.e. `GREEN` and `MAGENTA`.

```
 ------------------------
|  left   | green JPanel |
| JPanel  |______________|
|  with   |magenta Jpanel|
|3 JPanel |              |
|________________________|
```

Now the left `JPanel` will place `RED`, `BLACK` and `BLUE` `JPanel` on itself, with `GridBagLayout` as its `Layout Manager` with `RED and BLUE` having `weighty = 0.1`, and `BLACK` having `weighty = 0.8`

See this example code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample {
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel redPanel;
    private JPanel blackPanel;
    private JPanel bluePanel;
    private JPanel greenPanel;
    private JPanel magentaPanel;

    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public GridBagExample() {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        leftPanel = getPanel(Color.WHITE);
        leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        redPanel = getPanel(Color.RED.darker());
        blackPanel = getPanel(Color.BLACK);
        bluePanel = getPanel(Color.CYAN.darker().darker());
        greenPanel = getPanel(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());
        magentaPanel = getPanel(Color.MAGENTA);
        /**
          * @param : 
          * leftPanel : JPanel (with GridBagLayout), on which
          *               all other components will be placed.
          * redPanel : JPanel, which will be added to the leftPanel
          * 0 : specifies the grid X, which in this case is 0
          * 0 : specifies the grid Y, which in this case is 0
          * 1 : specifies the width for this grid (cell), we keeping 
          *     this default as 1
          * 1 : specifies the height for this grid (cell), we keeping
          *     this default as 1
          * GridBagConstraints.BOTH : allows JPanel to expand in both
          *     directions as the containing container expands (in 
          *     this case redPanel will expand both HORIZONTALLY and
          *     VERTICALLY, as leftPanel will expand)
          * weightx : This is the actual width the redPanel will occupy
          *           relative to all other components on the leftPanel
          * weighty : This is the actual height the redPanel will occupy
          *           relative to all other components on the leftPanel
          */
        addComp(leftPanel, redPanel, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 1.0, 0.1);
        addComp(leftPanel, blackPanel, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 1.0, 0.8);
        addComp(leftPanel, bluePanel, 0, 2, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 1.0, 0.1);
        addComp(contentPane, leftPanel, 0, 0, 1, 2,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.5, 1.0);
        addComp(contentPane, greenPanel, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.5, 0.3);
        addComp(contentPane, magentaPanel, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.5, 0.7);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        /*
         * Once you will add components to these
         * JPanels, then use pack(), instead of
         * setSize(). The use of the latter is 
         * just for illustration purpose only
         */
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp,
                            int x, int y, int width, int height,
                            int fill, double weightx, double weighty) {
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.gridwidth = width;
        gbc.gridheight = height;
        gbc.fill = fill;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(Color backColor) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(backColor);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the same :

[image: GRIDBAGLAYOUTIMAGE]