# gridBagLayout vs absoluteLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to make a GUI for a Bank Application in JAVA. Using absolute layout for my frame is so easy to create anything if I make use of WindowBuilder in eclipse but the problem with it is when I resize the frame. So that's why I chose to use gridBagLayout where I can use weightx/y to make my job easier. I kind of forgot how to use this layout properly so I got stuck at my first attempt to add a JPanel in my gridBagLayout main panel.

This is what I want to achieve (made in absolute layout):

[image]

And this is what I have (made in gridBagLayout):

[image]

If someone can point me what I have to change/add when I first add the flowLayout panel I would appreciate. Basically the white space of the first cell - I want to get rid of it and control it!

Here is some code:

```
    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
    flowLayout.setVgap(15);
    flowLayout.setHgap(15);
    flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 204));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
    add(panel, gbc_panel);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("European Bank");
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    panel.add(label);

    JLabel lblYourBankAccounts = new JLabel("Your Bank Accounts");
    lblYourBankAccounts.setForeground(new Color(153, 153, 153));
    lblYourBankAccounts.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 60, 0, 0);
    gbc_label.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gbc_label.gridx = 0;
    gbc_label.gridy = 1;
    add(lblYourBankAccounts, gbc_label);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(10, 60, 10, 10);
    gbc_scrollPane.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc_scrollPane.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 2;
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
```

Comment: I would recommend using a visual form designer, it is so much easier and quicker than doing it manually. eclipse, jformdesigner, netbeans, there are lots of options.

Comment: I solved my problem. I've commented 
              /*gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
  gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
  gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
  gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};*/

I am using WindowBuilder addon in eclipse. Actualy 50% of this code is generated. Maybe thats why I didnt understood why I had that white space.

Comment: @Chris : You can make your code a bit more readable, by making a simple function, that adds the component to the specified container, having `GridBagLayout` as its `Layout Manager` as shown in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17919032/1057230)

Comment: if you are using window builder in eclipse, you might take a look at using miglayout.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the built in Layout Customizer in **Netbeans**.
It's easy to learn from it. Hope it helps.

For Your type of problem try to adjust the weights of the component You want to strech.

Here's a screenshot how to do it: http://goo.gl/TBPY9i